# checking the states in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, enums, states

I wanted to animate an object in unity. so first, I want to check that what is my player states. I have to say that I use enum for naming the states.
here is my code for checking the state:

```
switch(PlayerStateController.playerStates)
    {
    case PlayerStateController.playerStates.idle:
        break;
    case PlayerStateController.playerStates.left:
        transform.Translate(new Vector3(-1.5f * Time.deltaTime, 0.0f, 0.0f));
        break;
    case PlayerStateController.playerStates.right:
        transform.Translate(new Vector3(1.5f * Time.deltaTime, 0.0f,
                                       0.0f));
        break;
    }
```

but I have an error:

> Expression denotes a 'type', where a 'variable', 'value' or 'method group' was expected

Comment: `switch(PlayerStateController.playerStates)`: you can't switch on a type. You need to switch on a variable, like `currentPlayerState`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class AnyClass {
    public enum PlayerState {
        idle,
        left,
        right
    }
}
```

-

```
public class AnyOtherClass {
    void DoStuff(PlayerState state) {
        switch (state) {
        case PlayerState.idle:
            break;
        case PlayerState.left:
            transform.Translate(new Vector3(-1.5f * Time.deltaTime, 0.0f, 0.0f));
            break;
        case PlayerState.right:
            transform.Translate(new Vector3(1.5f * Time.deltaTime, .0f, 0.0f));
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: this would be easy if enum and method both were in the same class. but my enum is in other class. how can I solve it?

Comment: you can place the enum everywhere in the project and it will still work as long as you import the namespace it is in.